# can we define two listening ports in a same server in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I did coding to access the webcamera of my laptop. Then I separately created another project for chat. They both use different server codes(in `node.js`). Now I want to merge them together in a single code, But my server side code when merged is showing error. Can any one help me with this? Below is my server side code for the merged project:

```
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient,

client=require('socket.io').listen(8888).sockets;

var static = require('node-static');

var http = require('http');

var file = new(static.Server)();

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

file.serve(req, res);

}).listen(8888);
```

Followed by other codes below...

Comment: Show the error as well please.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but Node.Js is single threaded, therefore it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you trying to bind two different applications (socket.io and the http server in your case) to the same port 8888. It is not allowed as you will receive this error:

```
EADDRINUSE, Address already in use
```

By calling the `listen` method twice you actually try to bind two applications to the same port passed as argument.

A solution will be to bind `socket.io` and the `server` to different ports.